# Using toggles from etoolbox to switch Sweave Schunks of code on and off

Tags: conditionals, sweave, etoolbox

I would like to use the toggles from `etoolbox` to direct Sweave to evaluate or not evaluate chunks of code. Example:

```
\newtoggle{FirstTime}
\toggletrue{FirstTime}
%\togglefalse{FirstTime}

\iftoggle{FirstTime}{
<<>
 read.csv("My Big Fat Data file.csv") -> MyData
@
}
```

The idea would be to read in the data at the beginning of the work session and then `\togglefalse` so it would not need to be read again. I am using Eclipse and StatET, so object MyData would be resident in memory and accessible to R throughout the session.

However, the above code evaluates regardless of the toggle value.

I know I can achieve this result by changing `eval=TRUE` to `eval=FALSE` - but using toggles would be cleaner and give more flexibility.

Comment: Problem might be related to the `@`. Try adding `\makeatletter` before the `\iftoggle` and a `\makeatother` after the closing `}`. You also should have an additional `{}` at the end for the case where the `\iftoggle` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Also your `\ifftoggle` lacks the ‘false’-part.

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to try the [`knitr` package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=knitr), which does this job more elegantly. See section 3.5 "Evaluation of Chunk Options" in the manual: https://github.com/downloads/yihui/knitr/knitr-manual.pdf

Your approach has two problems:

1. Sweave will not recognize `\iftoggle`, because it does not analyze the TeX context; the tex document is processed purely as character strings -- whenever it sees `<<>>=`, it will treat the following lines as R code, regardless of if you have `\iftoggle` above the code chunk;
2. you write more code by inserting `\iftoggle{FirstTime}{}` around your code chunks, and [this](https://gist.github.com/2561771) is how you can do it with less efforts in `knitr`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}

   <<controller>>=
   # this variable controls if a chunk should be evaluated
   dothis <- TRUE
   @

   <<chunk1, eval = dothis>>=
   print('say hello world')
   @

   <<chunk2, eval = !dothis>>=
   print('silence is gold')
   @

   \end{document}
   ```

If you find the syntax strange, you may read [how `knitr` differs with Sweave](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/); basically `knitr` makes your document really programmable.